# Sum of distinct values of vector of tuples in Rust

Tags: rust, iterator, tuples

I have a vector of tuples:

`let steel_forces = [(1, 2, 1), (3, 4, 2), (5, 6, 3)];`

Is there a way to obtain summation of single components in a single line? Result should be a tuple with these values:

`(9, 12, 6)`

I'm using following code but it doesn't look very rustic

```
let mut Ns = 0.0;
let mut Mxs = 0.0;
let mut Mys = 0.0;

for (force, mx, my) in steel_forces.iter() {
   Ns = Ns + force;
   Mxs = Mxs + mx;
   Mys = Mys + my;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What about using [`fold()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold)?

```rust
let (Ns, Mxs, Mys) = steel_forces
    .iter()
    .fold((0, 0, 0), |(Ns, Mxs, Mys), &(force, mx, my)| {
        (Ns + force, Mxs + mx, Mys + my)
    });
```